# java jLabel image does not update

Tags: java, image, netbeans, jlabel

I'm creating a feedback label that displays the picture that the user has chosen in a file dialog.

The moment when a picture file is selected, the label will update itself into that image of which the user has clicked.

The first time when the picture is chosen it works fine, however when another picture is chosen for the 2nd time onwards, it remains as the first picture.

Codes:

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //browse button
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setDirectory("C:\\");
        fd.setFile("*.jpg"); // jpg files only
        fd.setVisible(true);
        String filename = fd.getFile();
        if (filename == null) {
            System.out.println("You cancelled the choice");
        } else {
            savePicture("temp"); // save it in temp.jpg. This overwrites any existing picture. 
            ImageIcon imgThisImg = null; 
            imgThisImg = new ImageIcon(absfilePath+ "/temp.jpg"); 
            jLabel7.setIcon(null);
            jLabel7.setIcon(imgThisImg);
            jLabel7.revalidate();
            jLabel7.repaint();
        }
```

During debugging, the moment after savePicture() function is executed, the directory picture is updated. Therefore it's not an issue with overwritting the file. The file is overwritten correctly, why does it still display the previous image? Is there a cache or something that i need to clear?

Thanks.

Comment: OK guys i found the answer. All you need to do to refresh the image icon is : imgThisImg.getImage().flush();  Bamm done.

Comment: Or consider using ImageIO to read the file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using ImageIO to the read file works best. Can be achieved using the following line.
        `jLabel7.setIcon(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Cameron Gillespie\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\OnlineCabsClient\\src\\images\\taxiBackground.png")))));`

You are taking the label then setting the icon. Creating a new label and ImageIcon. Then using ImageIO to read the file. Reading the image and printing it to the label.